# How to compare simulated and experimental data?

Tags: plotting, fitting, error-tracking

I have numerically simulated and experimental data, I want to compare them and find the variation against numerical data. I do not have any idea about it. I just plotted experimental and simulated data. Using the ListLine plot code:

```
a1 = Import[
       "C:\\Users\\zone\\Dropbox\\2layer deformation\\MNS@2layer Def\\FEA \
       data\\O200umEX.txt", "Data"];
a2 = Import[
       "C:\\Users\\zone\\Dropbox\\2layer deformation\\MNS@2layer Def\\FEA \
       data\\O200umFEA.txt", "Data"];
ex = ListLinePlot[a1, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}];
FEA = ListLinePlot[a2, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[{ex, FEA}]
```

[image: plot]
Simulated data[simulated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QP66.jpg)
[experimental data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QP66.jpg)

Comment: Use `VarianceTest` and dependency tests like `CorrelationTest`, `PearsonCorrelationTest` and so on.

Comment: Are the plots of these data to be interpreted as histograms? I.e. is the vertical axis number of observations for each x-value? If so, you could test whether each of the two datasets come from the same distribution using `PearsonChiSquareTest`

Comment: Don't do any tests.  That requires at minimum a stated objective which is not described in your question.  What you can do is summarize the fit with maybe the root mean square error, histograms of the residuals, plots of residuals vs. the predictor variable, etc.

Comment: Were your links intended to provide the data or just the plot of the simulated and experimental data?